# Animation of line chart with D3.js (v4)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Is it possible to create an animation with D3.js (version 4)? In particular I want to create multiple line charts that "runs" from left to right like in this example with react-fusionchart:

http://jsfiddle.net/thadeuszlay/m18qaekm/12/

(just look at the example above.)

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var myDataSource = {
        "chart": {
            "caption": "Actual Revenues, Targeted Revenues & Profits",
                "subcaption": "Last year",
                "xaxisname": "Month",
                "yaxisname": "Amount (In USD)",
                "numberprefix": "$",
                "theme": "ocean"
        },
            "categories": [{
            "category": [{
                "label": "Jan"
            }, {
                "label": "Feb"
            }, {
                "label": "Mar"
            }, {
                "label": "Apr"
            }, {
                "label": "May"
            }, {
                "label": "Jun"
            }, {
                "label": "Jul"
            }, {
                "label": "Aug"
            }, {
                "label": "Sep"
            }, {
                "label": "Oct"
            }, {
                "label": "Nov"
            }, {
                "label": "Dec"
            }]
        }],
            "dataset": [{
            "seriesname": "Projected Revenue",
                "renderas": "line",
                "showvalues": "0",
                "data": [{
                "value": "15000"
            }, {
                "value": "16000"
            }, {
                "value": "17000"
            }, {
                "value": "18000"
            }, {
                "value": "19000"
            }, {
                "value": "19000"
            }, {
                "value": "19000"
            }, {
                "value": "19000"
            }, {
                "value": "20000"
            }, {
                "value": "21000"
            }, {
                "value": "22000"
            }, {
                "value": "23000"
            }]
        }]
    };

    var chartConfigs = {
        id: "revenue-profits-chart",
        renderAt: "revenue-profits-chart-container",
        type: "mscombi2d",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        dataFormat: "json",
        dataSource: myDataSource
    };

    React.render( < react_fc.FusionCharts {...chartConfigs
    }
    />,
        document.getElementById("chart-container")
    );
});
```

Comment: DuckDuckGo to the rescue: http://big-elephants.com/2014-06/unrolling-line-charts-d3js/

Comment: @Owen that's not v4, but the answer to OP is still "yes"

Comment: @thadeuszlay It would have been great that you showed that you made the effort to create yourself the linechart. It is after all a simple update from v3 to v4, and we could trust the people managing d3 to maintain line chart transitions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that: you just need to replace the methods that have changed from d3 v3 to v4, such as:

```
var parse = d3.timeParse("%b %Y");
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(-height),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickArguments(4);
```

Etc. Etc.

You can find the [working example on my bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/phvaillant/53b90038b9c5ac5f6b817a4f63fbc2af).
My example is the v4 update of [another bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/markmarkoh/8700606).
Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there an approach without a "curtain"? Because how would I go about if I wanted to use different graphs within one chart, e.g. a bar chart that is animated from bottom-to-top and a line chart from left-to-right?

Comment: Yes there is :) . You can animate the length of the line. This is actually the better approach, but the case you initially mentioned did not require it. Please read this post (http://blog.liftoffllc.in/2016/07/animated-line-graphs-using-d3.html) about it for animating the line. You will have to update to the methods of d3 v4 again, but that should not be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!